# How to use memcache (not memcached) in CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, memcached

Codeigniter comes with a memcached driver library, but this doesn't work for memcache (note the missing d). Anyone know how to implement memcache into codeigniter 2.1.3?

Comment: Which memcache, do you mean http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: @Yousf yes, i mean memcache, not memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like CI is only trying to use `Memcached` on their driver:

```
system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php
```

Check the `_setup_memcached` private function.

This [3rd party memcached library for codeigniter](https://github.com/tomschlick/memcached-library) has served us well. If you [look through the code](https://github.com/tomschlick/memcached-library/blob/master/libraries/memcached_library.php), you can see that it is prioritising `Memcache` over `Memcached` when setting up the client type. You can easily switch that if you want it the other way around.